# Using doctrine in a custom task

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm creating a task in a symfony 1.4 project, and I need to update some tables.

I've written :

```
<?php
class dataImportTask extends sfBaseTask
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->namespace = 'data';
    $this->name      = 'import';

    $this->addOptions(array(
        new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'environment', 'dev'),
    ));
  }

  public function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager(sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $options['env'], true));
    $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase()->getConnection();
  }
}
```

(Following the example found [on symfony-project.org](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line#chapter_13_accessing_the_database))

But when I execute the task, symfony says : "`Database "default" does not exist.`". Why doesn't the task uses the dbname defined in `databases.yml` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common problem when working with task. You have 2 options:

- named your doctrine connection `default` in the database.yml
- keep the same name in the database.yml and add an option on every tasks to retrieve the right database name.

For option #2, you have to add an option with the name (the one define in your `database.yml`) of your database and then change the way the `getDatabase` works:

In the database.yml:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
```

Based on the doctrine name above, add the option in your task:

```
<?php
class dataImportTask extends sfBaseTask
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->namespace = 'data';
    $this->name      = 'import';

    $this->addOptions(array(
        new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'environment', 'dev'),
        new sfCommandOption('connection', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The connection name', 'doctrine'),
    ));
  }

  public function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager(sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $options['env'], true));
    $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();
  }
}
```